# Keycloak email to admin after registration api

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm using keycloak 18.0.2-legacy in a docker-compose yaml file, and I want to be notified via email when a user uses the registrations API. Here an extract of my compose:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.3-alpine
    ...
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2-legacy
    container_name: keycloak
    restart: always
    networks:
      - pharaon-net
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: ${POSTGRESQL_DB}
      DB_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT: 8080
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      ...
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.2
    container_name: nginx
    ...
```

Could you help me?

Comment: I found online the doc to create the plugin at link https://medium.com/@adwaitthattey/building-an-event-listener-spi-plugin-for-keycloak-5bf9de1b0965